# CSV conversion script to Google sheet format is not behaving correctly

Tags: excel, csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm, currently using this automated script to convert automatically a dynamic csv sheet to google format, for further modification.

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Inventory.csv').next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

While the script works most of the time, however, occasionally instead of replacing the initial data, it will instead add a copy of the rows, leading to duplication.

This is the data how it supposed to be:

```
 House Number   Color   Family  Complaints 
 22             Red     Smiths  4
 A65            Blue    Stefans 5 
 18             Yellow  Dolmens 2
```

In perfect world, every time the script is activated, it will pull data from the dynamic csv and replace the existing data.

However, occasionally After a day of the script working every minute or 5 minutes. I find it in this state:

```
House Number    Color   Family  Complaints 
   22           Red     Smiths  4
   A65          Blue    Stefans 5 
   18           Yellow  Dolmens 2 
   22           Red     Smiths  4 
   A65          Blue    Stefans 5 
   18           Yellow  Dolmens 2 
   22           Red     Smiths  5 
   A65          Blue    Stefans 5 
   18           Yellow  Dolmens 3
```

As you can see instead of modifying the existing rows, occasionally it creates new set of rows for the data. Now this happens rarely, as after a day of running the script every 5 minutes, I only had perhaps 4-5 additional sets of rows.

You will notice that in the example, in the last set of rows the data varies, that just to show that due to the nature of the dynamic csv, the data will change. However, it should be overwriting the original, as opposed to, again, creating new sets of rows.

What would be the proper solution to this?

Comment: How is the csv file created?  I suspect the csv file is incorrect, Most like a line feed missing.

Comment: Possible comma issue.

Comment: Could it be that the source rows shrink? The script only replaces the csv length. If the previous length was greater then you could have duplicates. If that is the case add `sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()` before pasting.

Comment: @TheWizEd The original File does not seem to have any issues of that nature, its a standard csw created from an automated export. Delimiter: , Escape: Quotes

Comment: @RemcoE33 The number of rows and columns remain the same., If anything as the database grows the number of rows will increase

Comment: @PHSystemTester Could you clarify please?

Comment: Your OP showed it as though lines were bleeding together.  Now you're showing lines duplicated but seperated by new line.  I noticed that the last 3 lines have different complaint numbers.  Are you sure your csv is correct?  Can you view the csv in a text editor?

Comment: @TheWizEd Yes, the original post had formatting issues. The problem is with additional lines. Apologies. And yes the data changes as its pulled from a dynamic CSV, meaning that occasionally the new rows will have varying numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know for sure why it fails but maybe this is the solution. So we parse the csv ourselves.

The splitCsv() function is form another post here in SO. I cannot seem to find it...

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {
  const file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Inventory.csv').next();
  const csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  const csvData = csv.split("\n").map(row => splitCsv(row));
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}

/**
 * Splits the csv line to columns and escaping the comma's inside double qoutes.
 * @param {string} str the csv line string.
 * @returns {array} array of columns
 */
function splitCsv(str) {
  return str.split(",").reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
      if (acc.isConcatting) {
        acc.soFar[acc.soFar.length - 1] += "," + cur;
      } else {
        acc.soFar.push(cur);
      }
      if (cur.split('"').length % 2 == 0) {
        acc.isConcatting = !acc.isConcatting;
      }
      return acc;
    },
    { soFar: [], isConcatting: false }
  ).soFar;
}
```

Comment: Sadly when I try it, I just receive an error - 7:56:11 AM
Error
An unknown error has occurred, please try again later.

Comment: to follow up, 
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 4.

Additionally, the data seems to be pulled into incorrect columns, as in it starts from column 3 as opposed to column 1. All the data comes in with the quotation marks around it.